# How do I power many devices off of a low voltage microcontroller?

Tags: microcontroller, led, output, load

I'm new to electronics.
I have a GENIE 08 microcontroller, and I want to control multiple LEDs from one pin, and a few buzzers from another, and an LCD from one too.
I am worried that the power supplied from the output pins will not be suitable for this.
I am going to be running the controller from a 3V supply.
Is a relay with another supply going to be the best option for this project?
Any help in understanding this would be appriciated

Answer (score 1):

Your concerns are valid.

You will need transistors to drive the relay since it takes more current that an MCU pin can supply. You can skip the relay altogether. and only use transistors.

Comment: The transistors will be allowing current flow throught the output devices, which are powered by a separate power supply? Or could I use the 3V supply just with a step up device? Would the decrease in current be of any issue?

Comment: You could use the same 3.3V supply if it has sufficient voltage and current capability for your loads. The external transistor is to get around the MCU pin bottleneck. I wouldn't use a step up unless you really needed to stick to a single low voltage power source.

Comment: No, you really must not use the board's 3v3 supply with a "step up" to power other high power loads.  In addition to certainly not having the current rating for that, you don't want "grunge" from those loads getting back to the logic supply.  You need another supply with a common ground.  Possibly depending on the available regulator you may then be able to power the MCU board from the other supply and be left with a single mains supply.

Answer (score 1):

The [GENIE-08](https://www.genieonline.com/files/genie-08-microcontroller.pdf) is essentially a [Microchip PIC12F1822](https://www.microchip.com/wwwproducts/en/PIC12F1822) "in disguise".

The GENIE app note specifies the pin current limit as 25mA. As a general rule, it is much safer to use GPIOs to trigger external devices like MOSFETs or driver ICs to control high-power loads; it protects the pin from damage and allows you to control much higher power levels than the pin itself can support.

The pin would not source enough current to drive a relay coil; your best bet would be to look into logic-level MOSFETs. Use the GPIO to control the MOSFET gate, the MOSFET will control your LED and piezo loads.

Comment: A MOSFET does seem to make the most sense here. However, I am running low on available pins to use. Currently I am using pin 7 solely for status output, which is connected to the download socket. It can also be used for a digital output, so  would it be possible to connect an LED to it while the download socket is still in place? When I come to upload new code would it be an issue that the LED is drawing current from the pin?

Comment: It has been my experience that multiplexing the programming pins without isolation is tricky. A MOSFET gate may not appreciably affect the pin since it's inherently high impedance. Having an LED connected, well, that may be different.

Comment: @MaltedWheaties I would definitely buffer the LED with a MOSFET or buffer IC, or inverter IC, etc. Programming signals are in the MHz and their drivers  aren't really made to drive lines very hard to begin with. Even extending the parallel cable on a USB programmer can cause things to stop working properly. An LED hanging off the line drawing an upwards of 5mA will not be amendable to such things. Honestly, even a MOSFET with 15nC of total gate charge hanging off a programming makes me a bit wary since everything rides on being to program the processor. Aim for <1nC just to be safe.

Comment: That's probably a safe bet. What do you mean by a MOSFET buffer?

Comment: [I am designing a circuit that alerts the homeowner when they have left the door open](https://imgur.com/a/hqyFqwX). The door position is detected by the reed switch. Pin 7 is connected to the socket. [Unless I detect when the pin is being used for programming, and only let the pin control the LEDs when it isn't being used for programming?](https://imgur.com/a/mk7AcR1) But then again the gate might still affect the line :/

Answer (score 0):

You have to look into the Datasheet, there you can see how much current each GPIO is capable of. One LED should generally work... Multiple might be Difficult. Better be safe then sorry and use a MOSFET. If you have many things, you should consider using a Mosfet/transistor array. This is a chip which has all the FET/Transistor integrated. The ULN2800 Series is the first thing which comes to my mind.

You definitely shouldn't power a LCD from your MCU. Usually you connect the VCC, GND, LED +, LED - to your Powersupply. The MCU is only connected to the Datalines like D1-D4 (or D8, it depends),R/W and so on. If you want to disable the LCD, you could do it with a Transistor/FET and cut the Power to the LCD.

Comment: Note you typically must not "cut power" to devices while logic signals connected to them remain active, as this is typically a violation of data sheet requirements that signals not deviate more than a diode drop from the span of the power rails.  Doing so will tend to lead to power being drawn from the logic signals instead of the missing supply.

Comment: @ChrisStratton Very true... i was thinking about cutting the Power to the LED. This shouldn't be a problem, because the LED-Backlight is separated from the rest.